# How to ignore duplicate keys using the psycopg2 copy_from command copying .csv file into postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using Python.  I have a daily csv file that I need to copy daily into a postgresql table.  Some of those .csv records may be same day over day so I want to ignore those, based on a primary key field. Using cursor.copy_from,Day 1 all is fine, new table created.  Day 2, copy_from throws duplicate key error (as it should), but copy_from stops on 1st error.   Is there a copy_from parameter that would ignore the duplicates and continue?  If not, any other recommendations other than copy_from?

f = open(csv_file_name, 'r')

c.copy_from(f, 'mytable', sep=',')

Comment: No there is not. Suggestions: 1) Use [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) ON CONFLICT  while iterating over the records from the CSV file. This will be slow though 2) Create a staging table and `copy_from` to it and then `INSERT INTO <final_table> SELECT * FROM <staging_table> ON CONFLICT  ...`

Comment: the staging table worked. thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, then update your question with specific details, and things you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doing it with psycopg3.
Assumes the file is in the same folder as the script and that it has a header row.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from psycopg import sql

file = Path(__file__).parent / "the_data.csv"
target_table = "mytable"
conn = <your connection>

with conn.cursor() as cur:

    # Create an empty table with the same columns as target_table.
    cur.execute(f"CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table (LIKE {target_table})")

    # The csv file imports as text.
    # This approach tells postgres how to convert text to the proper column types.
    column_types = sql.Identifier(target_table)
    query = sql.SQL("COPY tmp_table FROM STDIN WITH(FORMAT csv, HEADER true)")
    typed_query = query.format(column_types)
    with cur.copy(typed_query) as copy:
        with file.open() as csv_data:
            copy.write(csv_data.read())

    cur.execute(
        f"INSERT INTO {target_table} SELECT * FROM tmp_table ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"
    )
```